# Syncronous AJAX whith jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have the following problem: there is no way to turn off asyncronous mode in $.ajax when using jsonp (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, async section). So the code

```
module = (function($)
{
    var result = null;

    var request = function(inputData)
    {
        $.ajax({
           url: "http://some.site",
           type: "post",
           data: inputData,
           dataType: "jsonp",
           success: function(response)
           {
                result = response;
           } 
        });

        return result;
    }
})($);

console.log(module.request());
```

will result in "null" on the first call, and in actual data on the second one.
So how can I make javascript wait for ajax to complete request and only after that return the result?

Comment: If you knew what JSONP was, you would understand why it **can't** be synchronous. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP Because it can't be synchronous, there is no way to make it do what you want.

Comment: You are making multiple mistakes here, you might need to take a few steps back. module has no method named request (request is a variable in your case). Also, you are returning `result` before the ajax is actually finished, you are going to have to defer the ajax result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. You'll have to re-organize your code to work asynchronously. Here, i'll do it for you.

```
var module = (function($) {
    var request = function(inputData) {
        return $.ajax({
           url: "http://some.site",
           //type: "post",
           data: inputData,
           dataType: "jsonp"
        });
    }
    return { request: request };
})($);

module.request().done(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

Also fixed a few other small mistakes, i assume those were just copy paste issues.

Comment: I thought of using .done() inside request() method, but it doesn't provide the functionality I need,  because output in console is just an example. The real need is:
    `variable = module.request()`
For unknown reasons I didn't write it in the first message.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Right, but you can't do that. it simply isn't possible.